# Base64 decode cannot decode all data

Tags: python

I'm using base64 encode the encrypt file then output the encode file then another python3 read the program
but when b64decode there is only 
part of front is decode

Python3.7.4

```
import ssl
import os
import time
import base64  
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

from base64 import b64encode
from base64 import b64decode

de_buff=512

en_data_read=open('encrypt_data',mode='r',encoding='utf-8')
en_data=en_data_read.read()
en_data=b64decode(en_data)
de_exec_payload(en_data)
```

## This is encrypt_data in files

```
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'b'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'b'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'b'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'b'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'b'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'b'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'b'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
```

it read only one block(first 684 decode)
others will not decode

Comment: I think the `=` character in the middle ends the base64 string.

Comment: yes your right , so I need remove '='?

Comment: Or split it up into several calls